# How to create new column which is choice from other 3 values by priority

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table which has 3 columns like id1, id2, id3. Now I want to have another table which have one id column, which is one of the values of (id1, id2, id3).

like so

```
if id1 is not null:
    id = id1
elif id2 is not null:
    id  = id2
else:
    id = id3
```

How can I implement such SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation COALESCE is supported so you can do

```
SELECT COALESCE(id1, id2, id3)
```

since COALESCE returns the first non-null value

Comment: SELECT COALESCE(id1, id2, id3) as id from table where id IS NOT NULL, get an error "Unrecognized name: id"?  How can I conditioned this